# Invalid mongodb uri Must begin with "mongodb://"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Any idea why i get this error?

this is the connect line

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://danielkmx:"+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW+"@node-rest-shop-5xfup.mongodb.net/test",
{
    useMongoClient:true
});
```

Comment: you are concatenating wrong change "mongodb+srv://" to "mongodb://"+srv+"://"

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates I got the same error.and solved with this link.You need to update your package.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same error, and it got resolved when I updated the mongoose package to the latest version.

Comment: which version did u upgrade to?

Comment: @LukAron it's a long time back. I don't recall. At present, i am using 5.3.16

Comment: I upgraded Mongoose to 5.10.11 and it is able to handle the new connection string format with "+srv".

Answer (score 17):

I think by now you have found an answer to this problem but I will explain, in the case that anyone else has the same problem

So generally we have 2 protocols(1- mongodb+srv:// & 2- mongodb://) right now to connect to a mongodb database.

the main difference between these 2 is the mongodb and its core version which you can find in the package-lock.json file, something like the code below:

```
"mongodb": {
  "version": "3.0.0", //Your MongoDB version
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/-/mongodb-3.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "",
  "requires": {
    "mongodb-core": "3.0.0"
  }
},
"mongodb-core": {
  "version": "3.0.0", //Your MongoDB version
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb-core/-/mongodb-core-3.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "",
  "requires": {
    "bson": "1.0.9",
    "require_optional": "1.0.1"
  }
},
```

This if you wanna use the mongodb+srv:// version then you need a driver of version 3.0.0 or higher which you can simply do by:

```
npm install mongodb@3.0.0
```

**Or higher

I hope you find this helpful and if this solution is working for you please confirm it that other users do not face our issue again

Comment: question is for connecting with mongoose. how can you solve that problem

Comment: dear @Yilmaz
as the error message was removed, and when I saw this question, I was working with MongoDB and got some errors with the protocols (1- mongodb+srv:// & 2- mongodb://) and MongoDB version, I thought it will be helpful to share a potential problem with older vs newer versions of MongoDB (this error can happen if you are wokring with mongoose as well)

If you are getting any specific bug, please share its error message as a Question or here, and I will take a look and if I can, I will definitely help on that

 :)

Comment: Dear @MehdiRoshanFekr :) i resolved that problem. i installed the new version of mongoose. thank you. i have  another problem. i connected to mongose but it is not writing to the db. i use mongose and in mongoose connect options i added "dbName="myDb" but it is not working.  warm regards :)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the solution and voted up for the question and very correct answers here.

In case someone wants to update the latest package(s), I suggest npm-check-updates (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) for smooth updating.

Install npm-check-updates:

```
    $ sudo npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Check latest updates of the used packages:

```
    $ ncu
```

Update packages:

```
    $ ncu -u
```

Then, install the updated packages:

```
    $ npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the following version of the mongoose helped me solve this problem

```
npm i mongoose@5.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but with `mongorestore` command. I did `brew update mongodb` which resulted in the following error.

`unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion`

I then uninstalled mongodb and installed database tools by running `brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools` which solved the problem for me and I was able to restore the database using following command:

`mongorestore --uri=mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.wtdv4.mongodb.net/<db-name> --db <db-name> <input-dir>`

Answer (score 0):

Although i had required versions of MongoDB, and mongoose, as i was making socket package for the application, my socket package was not up to date due to which it did not work, so crux is to ensure packages are updated to fit in new changes.