# How to connect mongodb atlas with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect a mongodb atas database i've just created with my nodejs program but I got this error :

> Error: Invalid mongodb uri
>   "mongodb+srv://loginr:aqpass5@cluster0-ymz55.mongodb.net/barcode?retryWrites=true".
>   Must begin with "mongodb://"

```
export default {
    "mongoUrl": "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0-ymz55.mongodb.net/barcode?retryWrites=true", 
}
```

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from '../config/index';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const connectToDb = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl, { useMongoClient: true });
        logger.info('Connected to mongo!!!');
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        logger.error('Could not connect to MongoDB');
    }
}

export default connectToDb;
```

Comment: I hope that the login data in the error message is not a real.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid mongodb uri Must begin with "mongodb://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980473/invalid-mongodb-uri-must-begin-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your structure... I have the 'myurl'-file in the folder 'setup' and the index.js file outside that map.:

In the myurl-file:

```
module.exports = {
mongoURL:"mongodb+srv://username:Password@cluster0-8htmv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"};
```

Make sure you have the password right with the right user.

In the 'index.js'-file:

```
const db = require('./setup/myurl').mongoURL; //directs to your other js-file

mongoose
.connect(db,**{useNewUrlParser: true, //this part is fairly new
    useUnifiedTopology: true}**)
.then(() => console.log("Success"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Good luck

Comment: What should be the version of mongoose and mongodb for this to be used?